# Returning a thread result to the Fragment using interface implementation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, interface

I have an application that shows News articles in a listview inside a fragment. 
When the fragment is first created, I start a thread that will fetch the list of articles (Stories) through an API call

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mContext =  getActivity();

        new GetStoriesThread(mContext,this).start();
```

Both the Fragment and the Thread implement the same Interface for passing the data from the thread to the Fragment

```
public interface GetStoriesThreadInterface {
    public void onGetStoriesThreadResult(final ArrayList<Story> result);
}
```

After the Thread is done processing, it will call the interface method and pass the data back to the calling Fragment.

**The problem**

Now when I get the result in the fragment, through this code:

```
    @Override
public void onGetStoriesThreadResult(final ArrayList<Story> result)
{
    if(result!=null)
    {
                mStoriesList.clear(); //mStoriesList is the list that i supply to the adapter of the ListView
                mStoriesList.addAll(result);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Exception here
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
04-28 18:03:58.432: E/ViewRootImpl(21513): com.says.news.Stories : Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I know that using `getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable...` solves the issue, but I dont understand why. And sometimes `getActivity()` returns null and that`s a whole different issue.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you calling onGetStoriesThreadResult() from within the working thread? You shouldn't. Consider using AsyncTask<> instead of bare Thread , override the onPostExecute() method and call your events from there.

Comment: Yes i am calling onGetStoriesThreadResult() from within the working thread, but I thought that was a proper use of Interfaces.
Isn't the method getting called in the Fragment class ?

Comment: Obviously not - whatever you call from a thread gets executed within that thread, and that shouldn't involve any memory that your main thread uses. onPreExecute and onPostExecute methods of the AsyncTask are run on the main thread so they are handy for such interactions.